# How to get data with websocket in a class and instantiate variable

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to get a websocket connection working in a class, because I need to access the variable `self.close`outside of the class.
The problem is that the connection is not established and I also can't access the variable inside `on_message`

How can I get it to work?

```
import websocket
import json


class WS:

    def __init__(self):

        self.socket = 'wss://ftx.com/ws/'

    def stream(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.socket,
            on_message=self.on_message,
            on_error=self.on_error,
            on_close=self.on_close)
        self.ws.run_forever()

    def on_open(self):

        print('connected')

        data = {'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'ticker', 'market': 'ETH-PERP'}
        self.ws.send(json.dumps(data))

    def on_close(ws):
        print('disconnected')

    def on_message(self,message):

        json_msg = json.loads(message)
        self.close = json_msg['data']['last']

    def get_data_out(self):

        return self.close
   
    def on_error(ws,error):
        print(error)
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. If you get error message then show FULL error in question (not in comment) as text (not image). We can't read in your mind. And don't expect that we will run code to see problem. Besides it can run correctly on our computers.

Comment: maybe create minimal working code so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: This is a minimal working code, and there's no error message. I wrote in the description that no connection is established, means nothing happens.

Comment: it is NOT minimal working code - If I put code in `script.py` and run `python script.py` then it makes nothing. It needs some code which creates object `WS()` and runs some loop from `websocket`. And `minimal working code` means that I can run it without adding extra code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to run your code

```
WS().stream()
```

but it doesn't work for me (even if I add missing `on_open=self.on_open`)

I found even ftx [documentation](https://docs.ftx.com/#websocket-api) and its [example](https://github.com/ftexchange/ftx/blob/master/websocket/client.py) with also use module `websocket` but I didn't test it.

But if I use different module [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/index.html) (with char `s`) instead of `websocket` (without char `s`) then I can subscribe channel and get values.

---

Minimal working example

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json

async def handler():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://ftx.com/ws/') as ws:
        
        # subscribe
        data = {'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'ticker', 'market': 'ETH-PERP'}
        await ws.send(json.dumps(data))

        # get all messages (not only with `update`)
        async for message in ws:
            print(message)

# --- main ---
     
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(handler())
```

To get only `last` value it needs to filter messages:

```
        async for message in ws:
            data = json.loads(message)
            if data['type'] == 'update':
                print(data['data']['last'])
```

But it still need to write more code if you want to use it as class.

---

**BTW:**

It seems `websocket` (without char `s`) is very old module and last updated was in 2010 and `websockets` (with char `s`) was updated in 2021 (few weeks/months ago).

https://pypi.org/project/websocket/

https://pypi.org/project/websockets/

---

**EDIT:**

In other question I found command which show more information about connection:

```
websocket.enableTrace(True)
```

and this shows errors because functions are executed with more values then you defined.
They have to get `websocket` as first argument (after `self`)

You have:

```
def on_open   (self):
def on_close  (ws):
def on_message(self, message):
def on_error  (ws, error):
```

but it has to be

```
def on_open   (self, ws):
def on_close  (self, ws):
def on_message(self, ws, message):
def on_error  (self, ws, error):
```

You also forgot `on_open=self.on_open`

---

Full working code

```
import websocket
import json

class WS:

    def __init__(self):
        self.socket = 'wss://ftx.com/ws/'
        self.close = None # default value at start

    def stream(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
                    self.socket,
                    on_message=self.on_message,
                    on_error=self.on_error,
                    on_close=self.on_close,
                    on_open=self.on_open
                  )

        print('run forever')
        self.ws.run_forever()
        
    def on_open(self, ws):
        print('on_open:', ws)

        data = {'op': 'subscribe', 'channel': 'ticker', 'market': 'ETH-PERP'}
        
        self.ws.send(json.dumps(data))

    def on_close(self, ws):
        print('on_close:', ws)

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        print('on_message:', ws, message)
        
        data = json.loads(message)

        if data['type'] == 'update':
            self.close = data['data']['last']

    def get_data_out(self):
        return self.close
   
    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print('on_error:', ws, error)
        
# --- main ---

websocket.enableTrace(True)  # if you want to see more information  
                             # but code works also without this line

WS().stream()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code and explanation! I didn't know I was using an old websocket library. Do you know how to get to use `self.close` outside of the class?

Comment: first `my_ws = WS()`, next you would have to run (in separated thread) `my_ws.stream()` and then you can get `my_ws.close`

Comment: Got it now, it works! THANKS!